# How to create an exogenous day of work week index variable from decomposition of daily time-series data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

I want to extract a day of work week index, that repeats itself every 5 days (business day). A monthly index would give 12 index values that repeat every 12 periods, instead of months I want to create the same index for the workweek. I have time-series data with only business day frequency (Monday -Friday). So annually I use 252 as the freq. If I decompose this daily series it creates a daily index by year, which creates an index for every business day of the year. In Python/Statsmodels, is there a way to create an index from this time series in which I can get the relative index value every 5 days?

I've tried various decompositions, by first changing the resampling frequency, before decomposing the time series, but I don't have a clue as to how to do this. The pseudo code below represents the workweek data I have for 2 years.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.tsa.api as tsa
import statsmodels.api as sm

vals = np.random.rand(504)
ts = pd.Series(vals)
df = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=["Stock"])
df.index = pd.Index(pd.date_range("2012/01/01", periods = len(vals), freq = 'D'))

comp_Stock = tsa.seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive', freq = 252)

comp_Stock.seasonal[:5]
```

It's hard to describe the expected results other than to say, the seasonal index above comp_Stock would create an index that repeats every 252 values, using this same timeseries data, I want an index that repeats every 5 days. The end goal is to extract this index as an exogenous variable for forecasting.

Comment: Are there holidays excluded in your data?  If not, can you not simply use integer division by 5?

Comment: I will check. I think this could work. So would I divide 252 by 5 and place the number in the freq argument?

Comment: ```pd.date_range("2012/01/01", periods = len(vals), freq = 'B')
``` You can use the letter B for busniess days in frequency. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html Look for Frequency String for a table of different Frequency Strings.

Comment: Thank you for the help Ben.